# How to use specific divs to measure Bootstrap's breakpoints?

Tags: css, css-grid, bootstrap-5, container-queries

Can [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/) provide responsive layouts for two columns whose mutual, vertical border can be dragged? [Answer: Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76462486/2450941), by reconfiguring Bootstrap to use [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_container_queries) rather than media queries. Container queries are supported by major browsers [since Feb 2023](https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries).

**Background:** Two divs are stacked side-by-side as columns. Between them is a draggable separator affordance. E.g., the leftmost div has the css `resize` property set to `horizontal`, while the rightmost has Bootstrap class `flex-grow-1`. The user can then drag the separator affordance to the left or right.

**Desired outcome:** Bootstrap's grid tiers inside the column divs should be chosen based on the divs' individual widths *as opposed* to relying on the viewport width.

Illustration (all gray divs have `class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg 4"`):

[image]

So, when using the `col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg 4`classes etc. in Bootstrap, how to best add logic to “do measurements based on the parent div” or “div with id #X”?

Comment: Is the *parent DIV* a `.container`? In any case, why not provide a [mcve] in addition to your images?

Comment: I don't think this is possible OOTB. You certainly can achieve that with CSS Grid or Flexbox.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I initially added a minimal reproducible example (see revision history), but took it away after adding the solution below, at which point I think the MRE didn't add value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each desired Bootstrap class, e.g. `col-sm-6`,`col-md-4` and `col-lg-3`, override the width set by Bootstrap's media queries and use a width based on [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_container_queries), as below. This allows the changes to be done only in CSS, with no changes to the HTML and no JavaScript, using vanilla Bootstrap classes, just adding a `ucq` (“use container queries”) class where desirable.

CSS:

```
.container-query-target { container-type: inline-size; }

/* ucq: use container queries */
.ucq .col-sm-6,
.ucq .col-md-4,
.ucq .col-lg-3,
{ width: 100%; }

@container (min-width:576px) {
    .ucq .col-sm-6 { width: 50%; }
}
@container (min-width:768px) {
    .ucq .col-md-4 { width: 33.33333333%; }
}
@container (min-width:992px) {
    .ucq .col-lg-3 { width: 25%; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row container-query-target ucq">
    <div class="test col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">Sample content</div>
</div>
```